# Writing zugferd compatible invoices using lualatex

Tags: luatex

I'm currently creating invoices for a business in germany using lualatex. Now I would like the invoices to be compatible with the electronic invoice standard zugferd, see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZUGFeRD.

The basic quest is to create a PDF/A-3 document and attach some XML data into it. Is there a lualatex style solution for both tasks?

Comment: A bit of PDF internals is discussed here (German only): https://blog.speedata.de/2017/07/24/zugferd/  (Shameless plug: the speedata Publisher, based on LuaTeX, is able to include ZUGFeRD files.)

Comment: @topskip: Thanks, that is already a start. Starting from https://github.com/speedata/publisher/commit/33bb78b51510ce830b61f26865e6ff92b237baa5#diff-8459393eeac209a1dfa8681c04ed59b1 should give me some hints.